# Why can I bind two sockets to the same port on Windows?

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

I just found that - on Windows 10 - I can bind two sockets on the (presumably) same TCP port. The trick is binding one socket to all interfaces (0.0.0.0:12345) and the other one to localhost.

Consider this Python snippet for demonstration:

```
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s1.bind(("0.0.0.0", 12345))
s2.bind(("127.0.0.1", 12345))
```

Windows 10 happily accepts this configuration while on Linux this fails with `Address already in use`.

I know network stacks are different on these OSes, but I didn't expect this particular issue.

The problem I have is that this test is used some legacy products I ought to take care of and I'm wondering whether there are ways to make Windows not allowing this multiple bind.

Update:
I forgot to state my questions:

- Why is that so?
- Are there ways to change this behavior?

Comment: To avoid the behavior on Windows, enable the [`SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/so-exclusiveaddruse) socket option. See [Using SO_REUSEADDR and SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/using-so-reuseaddr-and-so-exclusiveaddruse) on MSDN for more details.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot @RemyLebeau. I did not know about this option. `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE, 1)` really solves the problem presented here.

Comment: You should put that into an answer so that I can give you credits.

Comment: For reasons yet unknown to me this doesn't solve my actual, more complex problem. I have a mysqld running on 0.0.0.0:<port> and `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` in the test process doesn't trigger the failure yet. But that's something I gotta work our in more detail now.

Comment: "*doesn't trigger the failure yet*" - it should be, according to the table provided in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/using-so-reuseaddr-and-so-exclusiveaddruse). In what order are the two processes binding their sockets, and what is each process binding to exactly?

Comment: That's what I don't know exactly. I assume it's binding to 0.0.0.0 but then again it's mysqld and I need to look up things in its source code (again! sigh!). But yes, the table you provided indicates that the second bind should fail.

Comment: Use a tool like [netstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) or [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to see what mysqld is actually binding to.

Comment: `netstat -nq` says that mysqld binds on TCP `0.0.0.0:12345` and the process is still running. If I did understand all of this correctly a second process binding to 127.0.0.1:12345 with `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` set should fail then, is that all correct? 'Cause the thing is that it just doesn't :)

Comment: "*mysqld binds on `TCP 0.0.0.0:12345` ... a second process binding to `127.0.0.1:12345` with `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` set should fail*" - yes, it should, provided `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` is successfully enabled, are you checking for that?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it is enabled. `getsockopt(...)` returns 1, then the (double) bind succeeds. Of course, the first bind of mysqld is using its own socket options, but that shouldn't matter then.

Comment: Nevermind. It is operating as intended. I wasn't reading the entire article before. I was looking at the table that shows the behavior for XP and earlier, but I didn't see the other table (in the "Enhanced Socket Security" section) that shows behavior in newer Windows versions that actually allows your scenario to let the 2nd bind succeed if both binds are under the same user account, but not under different user accounts.

Comment: Alright, I gotta accept that then. Thank you very much!